# TypeError: fromarray() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have been asking questions on StackOverflow but have not been getting any positive responses. Got banned multiple times from posting further questions. Please provide help this time.

I want to perform custom object detection using custom trained YOLOv5 model on a real-time video feed taken from the webcam. I am using Django for this purpose (later on I will connect this with React.js frontend). I have been successful with accessing the webcam feed using Django but when I try to run my custom yolov5 model on the video feed. I am getting this error and there is no video showing up in index.html.

```
[12/Jun/2022 02:43:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 329
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mh_s1\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "c:\users\mh_s1\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 183, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "D:\University\FYP\FYP-CovidDefence\stream\webcam\views.py", line 42, in stream
    data=im.fromarray()
TypeError: fromarray() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj'
```

Here is my views.py file code:

```
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
import cv2
from PIL import Image as im
import yolov5
from yolov5.utils.general import (check_img_size, non_max_suppression, scale_coords, 
                                  check_imshow, xyxy2xywh, increment_path)
from yolov5.utils.torch_utils import select_device, time_sync
from yolov5.utils.plots import Annotator, colors

import io

import torch


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')

# Change this to the correct path
path_hubconfig = (r"D:\University\FYP\FYP-CovidDefence\stream\ObjectDetection\yolov5")
path_weightfile = (r"D:\University\FYP\FYP-CovidDefence\stream\ObjectDetection\yolov5\best.pt")  # or any custom trained model

model = torch.hub.load(path_hubconfig, 'custom', path=path_weightfile, source='local')


def stream():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            print("Error: failed to capture image")
            break
        results = model(frame, augment=True)
        # process
        #annotator = Annotator(frame, line_width=2, pil=not ascii)
        for i in results.render():
            data=im.fromarray()
            data.save('demo.jpg')
        #cv2.imwrite('demo.jpg',frame)
        #print(results)    
 
        image_bytes = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tobytes()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + open('demo.jpg', 'rb').read() + b'\r\n')

def video_feed(request):
    return StreamingHttpResponse(stream(), content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

Comment: have you considered passing some arguments to `Image.fromarray()`? it's a **very bad idea** to rename `Image` to be `im`. -- take the [tour], review [ask] and [mre]. positive responses happen when you've debugged your code, when the error message *doesn't* tell you what's wrong and when the documentation *doesn't* tell you exactly how to use the function you're calling

Comment: be very careful about color channel order. OpenCV's VideoCapture gives you BGR. does your model expect that? does your model return RGB order because that's what PIL will assume...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I actually forgot to pass 'i' to fromarray()

```
for i in results.render():
    data=im.fromarray(i)
```

Comment: You make silly mistakes and ask questions repeatedly, no wonder you get banned. Please take care before posting questions. Also check for typos and debug your code before posting. I have come across accounts getting banned for making repeated careless mistakes.